# Count number of 1 digits in 11 to the power of N

Tags: algorithm

I came across an interesting problem:

How would you count the number of 1 digits in the representation of 11 to the power of N, `0<N<=1000`.

Let **d** be the number of 1 digits

> **N=2**    11^2 = 121   **d=2**
>
> **N=3**    11^3 = 1331  **d=2**

Worst time complexity expected `O(N^2)`

The simple approach where you compute the number and count the number of 1 digits my getting the last digit and dividing by 10, does not work very well. 11^1000 is not even representable in any standard data type.

Comment: How big can `N` be? `sum(1 for i in str(11**100000) if i == '1')` runs in under a second in Python. If it's up to `1000`, implementing classic big numbers like paxdiablo described should work fine.

Comment: @IVlad I guess only "standard data" types can be used, like int, maybe long, string etc. And the algorithm solution should programming language independent

Comment: @Kent you are correct about the data types - only standard ones, you don't depend on any language or 3rd party library.

Comment: @IVlad I edited the question to show the values of N

Comment: You can implement big numbers easily for this problem using only what you describe. I think that's the easiest way to go.

Comment: If you use big number library you can actually do it in O(n*logn) since fast exponentiation takes O(logn) time.

Comment: you can't use big numbers library

Comment: this is a codility question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Powers of eleven can be stored as a string and calculated quite quickly that way, *without* a generalised arbitrary precision math package. All you need is multiply by ten and add.

For example, `111` is `11`. To get the *next* power of `11` (`112`), you multiply by `(10 + 1)`, which is effectively the number with a zero tacked the end, added to the number: `110 + 11 = 121`.

Similarly, `113` can then be calculated as: `1210 + 121 = 1331`.

And so on:

```
11^2   11^3    11^4     11^5      11^6

 110   1210   13310   146410   1610510
 +11   +121   +1331   +14641   +161051
 ---   ----   -----   ------   -------
 121   1331   14641   161051   1771561
```

So that's how I'd approach, at least initially.

---

By way of example, here's a Python function to raise 11 to the n'th power, using the method described (I *am* aware that Python has support for arbitrary precision, keep in mind I'm just using it as a demonstration on how to do this an an *algorithm,* which is how the question was tagged):

```
def elevenToPowerOf(n):
    # Anything to the zero is 1.

    if n == 0: return "1"

    # Otherwise, n <- n * 10 + n, once for each level of power.

    num = "11"
    while n > 1:
        n = n - 1

        # Make multiply by eleven easy.

        ten = num + "0"
        num = "0" + num

        # Standard primary school algorithm for adding.

        newnum = ""
        carry = 0
        for dgt in range(len(ten)-1,-1,-1):
            res = int(ten[dgt]) + int(num[dgt]) + carry
            carry = res // 10
            res = res % 10
            newnum = str(res) + newnum
        if carry == 1:
            newnum = "1" + newnum

        # Prepare for next multiplication.

        num = newnum

    # There you go, 11^n as a string.

    return num
```

And, for testing, a little program which works out those values for each power that you provide on the command line:

```
import sys

for idx in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
    try:
        power = int(sys.argv[idx])
    except (e):
        print("Invalid number [%s]" % (sys.argv[idx]))
        sys.exit(1)

    if power < 0:
        print("Negative powers not allowed [%d]" % (power))
        sys.exit(1)

    number = elevenToPowerOf(power)
    count = 0
    for ch in number:
        if ch == '1':
            count += 1

    print("11^%d is %s, has %d ones" % (power,number,count))
```

When you run that with:

```
time python3 prog.py  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1000
```

you can see that it's both accurate (checked with `bc`) and fast (finished in about half a second):

```
11^0 is 1, has 1 ones
11^1 is 11, has 2 ones
11^2 is 121, has 2 ones
11^3 is 1331, has 2 ones
11^4 is 14641, has 2 ones
11^5 is 161051, has 3 ones
11^6 is 1771561, has 3 ones
11^7 is 19487171, has 3 ones
11^8 is 214358881, has 2 ones
11^9 is 2357947691, has 1 ones
11^10 is 25937424601, has 1 ones
11^11 is 285311670611, has 4 ones
11^12 is 3138428376721, has 2 ones
11^1000 is 2469932918005826334124088385085221477709733385238396234869182951830739390375433175367866116456946191973803561189036523363533798726571008961243792655536655282201820357872673322901148243453211756020067624545609411212063417307681204817377763465511222635167942816318177424600927358163388910854695041070577642045540560963004207926938348086979035423732739933235077042750354729095729602516751896320598857608367865475244863114521391548985943858154775884418927768284663678512441565517194156946312753546771163991252528017732162399536497445066348868438762510366191040118080751580689254476068034620047646422315123643119627205531371694188794408120267120500325775293645416335230014278578281272863450085145349124727476223298887655183167465713337723258182649072572861625150703747030550736347589416285606367521524529665763903537989935510874657420361426804068643262800901916285076966174176854351055183740078763891951775452021781225066361670593917001215032839838911476044840388663443684517735022039957481918726697789827894303408292584258328090724141496484460001, has 105 ones

real    0m0.609s
user    0m0.592s
sys     0m0.012s
```

That may not necessarily be `O(n2)` but it should be fast enough for your domain constraints.

---

Of course, given those constraints, you can make it `O(1)` by using a method I call pre-generation. Simply write a program to generate an array you can plug into your program which contains a suitable function. The following Python program does exactly that, for the powers of eleven from 1 to 100 inclusive:

```
def mulBy11(num):
    # Same length to ease addition.

    ten = num + '0'
    num = '0' + num

    # Standard primary school algorithm for adding.

    result = ''
    carry = 0
    for idx in range(len(ten)-1, -1, -1):
        digit = int(ten[idx]) + int(num[idx]) + carry
        carry = digit // 10
        digit = digit % 10
        result = str(digit) + result

    if carry == 1:
        result = '1' + result

    return result

num = '1'

print('int oneCountInPowerOf11(int n) {')
print('  static int numOnes[] = {-1', end='')
for power in range(1,101):
    num = mulBy11(num)
    count = sum(1 for ch in num if ch == '1')
    print(',%d' % count, end='')
print('};')
print('  if ((n < 0) || (n > sizeof(numOnes) / sizeof(*numOnes)))')
print('    return -1;')
print('  return numOnes[n];')
print('}')
```

The code output by this script is:

```
int oneCountInPowerOf11(int n) {
  static int numOnes[] = {-1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,1,4,4,1,5,5,1,5,3,6,6,3,6,3,7,5,7,4,4,2,3,4,4,3,8,4,8,5,5,7,7,7,6,6,9,9,7,12,10,8,6,11,7,6,5,5,7,10,2,8,4,6,8,5,9,13,14,8,10,8,7,11,10,9,8,7,13,8,9,6,8,5,8,7,15,12,9,10,10,12,13,7,11,12};
  if ((n < 0) || (n > sizeof(numOnes) / sizeof(*numOnes)))
    return -1;
  return numOnes[n];
}
```

which should be blindingly fast when plugged into a C program. On my system, the Python code itself (when you up the range to `1..1000`) runs in about 0.6 seconds and the C code, when compiled, finds the number of ones in 11<sup>1000</sup> in 0.07 seconds.

Comment: Probably not really `O(n^2)` as requested, but you can speed it up by working in a base that's a higher power of 10. For example, in base `10^4`. Should be pretty efficient.

Comment: I thought about this, but you still can't represent the intermediate results. So you have to work out a way to do the addition digit by digit, which complicates things

Comment: I don't really see what advantage this approach holds over something like square and multiply, and it's quite a bit slower. When using `pow(11, power)`, your example `prog.py` runs in `0m0.029s` on my machine.

Comment: @Joost and how would you implement `pow` to be that fast with big numbers in a language that doesn't have it?

Comment: @Joost, I know Python has the ability to handle massive number built in, but most languages do not. My intent was to show how to do it as an algorithm (as per the tag) without have to implement something like GMP or MPIR in full. All you need is the multiply by ten (simple in a base-10 string) and adding two numbers. I just happen to like Python as my pseudo-code language :-)

Comment: I stand corrected. It felt like the problem could be reduced by using square&mult, but you're right that it requires support for big integer multiplication, which is actually more complex than the problem at hand.

Comment: I've actually taken advantage of much simpler arbitrary precision code in the past, in one case all I needed was a doubling operation and adding a small integer. I'm not necessarily a big fan of dragging in a behemoth like GMP when my needs are simple, especially when it has a nasty habit of just exiting when it runs out of memory, something I find rather bizarre in a general purpose library :-)

Comment: could pack the step result (num) in linkedlist, so that the calculation could be done in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my concise solution.

```
def count1s(N):
    # When 11^(N-1) = result, 11^(N) = (10+1) * result = 10*result + result
    result = 1
    for i in range(N):
        result += 10*result

    # Now count 1's
    count = 0
    for ch in str(result):
        if ch == '1':
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

En c#:

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = Elevento(1000);
        var countOf1 = res.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Count(s => s == 1);
        Console.WriteLine(countOf1);
    }

    private static string Elevento(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return "1";
        //Otherwise, n <- n * 10 + n, once for each level of power.
        var num = "11";
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            // Make multiply by eleven easy.
            var ten = num + "0";
            num = "0" + num;
            //Standard primary school algorithm for adding.
            var newnum = "";
            var carry = 0;
            foreach (var dgt in Enumerable.Range(0, ten.Length).Reverse())
            {
                var res = int.Parse(ten[dgt].ToString()) + int.Parse(num[dgt].ToString()) + carry;
                carry = res/10;
                res = res%10;
                newnum = res + newnum;
            }

            if (carry == 1)
                newnum = "1" + newnum;
            // Prepare for next multiplication.
            num = newnum;
        }
        //There you go, 11^n as a string.
        return num;
    }
```